# Convert \r\n characters to new line in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to be able to convert \r\n characters in a string to new lines

Example
John is waiting now.\r\nCan we tell you about him. \r\nHe is a great person

Converted to

John is waiting now.

Can we tell you about him.

He is a great person

Tried this but to no avail

```
nl2br(text: string) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
}
```

Comment: Do you read the \r\n in the text as you wrote it?

Comment: Yes. It is part part of a large text

Comment: ...So the are escaped

Comment: I am reading a text file that contain the character \r\n , basically a .sql file. So i have to find a way to escape it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be due to the fact that your `\r\n` characters might be visible because they are "over escaped".

Furthermore I don't know exactly the context your replace has to be performed but I don't think you have to replace them by a `<br/>`

You could thus do something silly like

```
nl2br(text: string) {
    return text.replace('\\r\\n', '\n');
   //or return text.replace('\\r\\n', '<br/>') if it is really what you need
}
```

Note also that if you have a mix of escaped `\n` and `\r`, you can

```
nl2br(text: string) {
    return text.replace(/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/gi, '\n');
   //or ...'<br/>');
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`\n` will show as line break if you apply below style to the element:

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

Comment: this worked like this
      `<ion-card-content [ngStyle]="{ 'white-space': 'pre-wrap' }"></ion-card-content>`