# Ionic4 show Text with line breaks

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want that the user can insert a text in an input field with multiple lines with the enter key. Then I want so save the text in a string and then send it to the backend. On the Detail-Page of the app I want to show the inserted text but with line breaks.

In the html file for the Input I tried this

```html
<div>
    <ion-item>
          <ion-textarea rows="5" name="description" type="text" 
               placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="description" required>
          </ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

In the .ts I encode the string of description

```
 this.description = encodeURI(this.description);
```

But when I want to show the inserted Text in the other html File

```
<ion-col size="12">
    <div class="idea-description">
      <ion-text style = "white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ idea.description }}</ion-text>
    </div>
```

it only shows the encoded text but there are no line breaks.

Comment: What happens if you don't encode `description`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759780/1026038), so I wanted to share here in case you hadn't found it yet.

`\n` will show as a line break if you apply below style to the element:

`white-space: pre-wrap`

I added this to the  element, and the data now shows with the line breaks in my `<ion-text>` element.

```
<ion-card-content class="" style="padding-top:0; white-space: pre-wrap;">
            <ion-text [innerHtml]="notification.content"></ion-text>
</ion-card-content>
```